# HTML Standards on <br> usage

Tags: html, standards

Apparently, HTML5 explicitly states that `<br>` tags must be used within the content of elements for example as in `<p>` tags below:

```
<p> Line 1 <br> Line 2 </p>
```

However, I don't see that the same is true with HTML 4.01. So, it seems that can use the `<br>` tags this way as well to force a line break:

```
Line 1 <br> Line 2 <br> ..
```

Can someone confirm how true or untrue is what I have here according to both the standards?

Comment: Technically, aren't you always within the context of another element anyway, barring being outside the root element? `<!DOCTYPE html><title>Example</title><br>` validates as HTML5 just fine. On the other hand, `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/strict.dtd"><title>Example</title><br>` does *not* validate as HTML 4.01...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1 says:

```
<!ELEMENT BODY O O (%block;|SCRIPT)+ +(INS|DEL) -- document body -->
```

`%block` resolves as:

```
<!ENTITY % block
     "P | %heading; | %list; | %preformatted; | DL | DIV | NOSCRIPT |
      BLOCKQUOTE | FORM | HR | TABLE | FIELDSET | ADDRESS">
```

and then:

```
<!ENTITY % heading "H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6">

<!ENTITY % list "UL | OL">

<!ENTITY % preformatted "PRE">
```

There is no sign of BR there, so in HTML 4 you also need to place your line breaks inside paragraphs or some other suitable element.

---

HTML 4.01 Transitional is different … but why worry about old standards in the first place? The point of having new standards is to improve upon the old ones and fix the bits that don't make sense.

Comment: When you said "HTML 4.01 Transitional is different" did you mean that it doesn't comply well with the standard for using almost-quirks mode? I have checked the code with `<br>` tags without paragraphs using a validator and it has been resulted to be passed.

Comment: There is nothing standard about (almost) quirks mode. When I said HTML 4.01 Transitional is different, I just meant that it has different rules (because it has more backwards compatibility with HTML 3.2 as it is there to help transition to HTML 4.01).

Comment: I don’t see what quirks mode has to do with this. HTML 4.01 Transitional is part of the W3C Recommendation, so it’s as “standard” as HTML 4.01 Strict (though not recommended for new pages).

Answer (score 0):

You can use br tag anywhere on your web page.

Permitted parent elements are described here: (Phrasing Content) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FContent_categories#Phrasing_content

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 CR description of the [`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) says: “br elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content, as in poems or addresses.” It also says: “br elements must not be used for separating thematic groups in a paragraph”, with an example about putting form fields on separate lines. This is rather vague, but it seems to say that `br` is only for line breaks that are *part of the text* instead of being used just for formatting content.

There is no requirement that `br` elements should be used only “within the content of elements” any more than other elements in document body. Out of necessity, anything in the body is inside the `body` element (even if the `<body>` and `</body>` tags are omitted). HTML5 does not require any wrapper like `p` in the same sense as HTML 4.01 requires.

The following is valid HTML5:

```
<!document html>
<title> </title>
SPLENDOR of ended day, floating and filling me!<br>
Hour prophetic—hour resuming the past!<br>
Inflating my throat—you, divine average!<br>
You, Earth and Life, till the last ray gleams, I sing.
```

Note that HTML5 is work in progress. It is probable that it will proceed from CR status to W3C Recommendation, or “standard”, with minor changes. But hair-splitting “semantical” statements like the one about being “actually part of the content” may well be changed.